# Programatically set selected option of select

Tags: magento2, forms, menu

I have a form which defines this field

```
    $subMenuType = $fieldset->addField(
        'mega_sub_content_type',
        'select',
        [
            'label' => __('Submenu Content'),
            'title' => __('Submenu Content Type'),
            'name' => 'mega_sub_content_type',
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $model->getSubMenuContentOptions(),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );
```

And here are the options(but I don't have any setter for that ^^ )

```
public function getSubMenuContentOptions()
{
    return [
        self::SUB_CONTENT_TYPE_CHILD_ITEMS => __('Child menu items'),
        self::SUB_CONTENT_TYPE_STATIC_BLOCK => __('Static Blocks'),
        self::SUB_CONTENT_TYPE_CUSTOM_CONTENT => __('Custom Content')
    ];
}
```

When I try to set this field it keep failing (well the menu item is saved but the field keep having his default  Child menu items value.

```
$data['mega_sub_content_type'] = __('Static Blocks');
```

This is how the menu item is saved

```
use Ubertheme\UbMegaMenu\Model\ItemFactory;
$model = $this->menuItemFactory->create()
    ->setData($data)
    ->save();
```

Comment: Looks like you're setting title instead of option value. How about $data['mega_sub_content_type'] = self::SUB_CONTENT_TYPE_STATIC_BLOCK

Comment: @RomanKabanov Almost, the real issue here was that the __function weren't returning the value I thought, so I had to pass the key static-blocks